# Binary XML file line #32: Failed to resolve attribute at index 1: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f0300cc a=-1}

Tags: android, android-menu, android-popupwindow

I want to show PopupMenu it is inside recycerview but
When i click menuButton app crashing and to finding the issue i removed  showPopupMenuMenu() method calling from setOnClickListener and replaced with toast it is working fine 
The problem is in showPopupMenuMenu() method any one please help me to solve this issue

```
holder.menuButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               try{
                   showPopupMenuMenu(holder,position);
               }catch (Exception e){
                   Log.e("showPopupMenuMenu",e.getMessage()+"");
               }
            }
        });

private void showPopupMenuMenu(MyViewHolder holder, final int position){
        //creating a popup menu
          PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(context, holder.menuButton);
        //inflating menu from xml resource
        popup.inflate(R.menu.recyclerview_option_menu);
        //adding click listener
       try{
           popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
               @Override
               public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                   switch (item.getItemId()) {
                       case R.id.edit_menu:
                           //handle menu1 click
                           if (context instanceof MyAddressActivity) {
                               ((MyAddressActivity) context).openEditAddressActivity(position, true);
                           } else if (context instanceof CheckoutLocationActivity) {
                               ((CheckoutLocationActivity) context).openEditAddressActivity();
                           }
                           break;
                       case R.id.delete_menu:
                           //handle menu2 click
                           if (context instanceof MyAddressActivity) {
                               ((MyAddressActivity) context).deleteAddressItem(position);
                           } else if (context instanceof CheckoutLocationActivity) {
                               ((CheckoutLocationActivity) context).mCheckoutLocationActivityPresenter.deleteAddressItem(position);
                           }
                           break;

                   }
                   return false;
               }
           });
       }catch (Exception e){
           Log.e("showPopupMenuMenu","setOnMenuItemClickListener  "+e.getMessage()+"");
       }
        //displaying the popup
        popup.show();
}
```

Binary XML file line #32: Failed to resolve attribute at index 1: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f0300cc a=-1}

R.menu.recyclerview_option_menu

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/edit_menu"
        android:title="@string/edit" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/delete_menu"
        android:title="@string/delete" />

</menu>
```

Comment: add `recyclerview_option_menu` with question .

Comment: Can you add your menu XML file ? You can also try `popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_menu, popup.getMenu());`

Comment: added please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this please;

```
openPopUpMenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(activity, v);
            popupMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.pop_up_menu, popupMenu.getMenu());
            popupMenu.show();

            popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {

                    if (menuItem.getTitle().equals("1. item title")) {
                        //do something
                    } else if (menuItem.getTitle().equals("2.item Title")) {
                        // do something
                    } 
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Binary XML file line #32: Failed to resolve attribute at index 1: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f0300cc a=-1}

Comment: What does it mean? Please check your code and xml file. You are missing something.. my code needs to work.

Comment: it is now working the problem is i am  useing context and i replace it with getactivity()

Comment: Try to YourAdapter.this or you can set a parameter to your constructor as a (Activity activity) and initialize your context to activity. this.context=activity in your adapter constructor

İf works, please make it accepted answer

Answer (score 2):

You should use **import android.widget.PopupMenu;** librariy.
You shuldn't androidx.appcompat.widget this isnt work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

If your using PopupMenu inside Adapter make sure tht Data passing to Constructor should be like

```
 AddressAdapter addressAdapter=new AddressAdapter(AddressList.this,addressModels);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(addressAdapter);
```

instead of

```
 AddressAdapter addressAdapter=new AddressAdapter(getApplicationContext(),addressModels);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(addressAdapter);
```

Note : Pass Activity ".this" not "ApplicationContext()"